# how to perform npm install without pruning installed dependencies?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm using npm v7 and need to install dependencies without pruning the existing ones (even if they are not mentioned in the package.json). I have tried `--package-lock=false` and `--package-lock false` - neither seems to work [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#package-lock)

Comment: This is so damning! I'm trying to use install-local with a scenario and it completely breaks due to auto-prune! Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: I found this thread where people are so annoyed by it, but no solution 5 years later! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16853